# How to query aggregated values from multiple table in EF Core in one query?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I want to query aggregated values from multiple tables like this.

```sql
SELECT
  (SELECT MAX(`A`) FROM `TableA`) as `MaxA`,
  (SELECT COUNT(`A`) FROM `TableA` WHERE A > 55) as `CountA`,
  (SELECT MIN(`B`) FROM `TableB`) as `MinB`
```

Is there a way to do something like this in EF Core in one query?

Comment: Something like it, sure: `var x = new { A = ctx.TableA.Max(a => a.A), B = ctx.TableB.Max(b => .B)    };` - I get the feeling you'll say "but it runs two queries" - yes, but notionally, so does yours..

Comment: Thank you @CaiusJard. I forgot to mention that I want to do it in a single trip to database. I updated the question.

Comment: *"single trip to database"* - why?

Comment: Maybe for better response time. In some cases, query like this got to be called multiple times in a small time period. Going multiple trips to database increases response time.

Comment: The time for a query depends on lots of factors including the amount of data transferred and size of database.  Max and Min only return one value each from the database.  Doing the search in Core would require returning the entire database which may take a lot of time.  If you want only one query to database than you can create a stored procedure in the database which returns both min and max.

Comment: *Maybe for ..* -so you don't actually know it's a problem and this is a premature optimization? You could modify the above so that it does MaxAsync and launch all queries in parallel.. but still, make sure it's a problem first ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `UNION ALL` for queries.

```cs
var query = ctx.TableA.GroupBy(x => 1)
    .Select(g => g.Max(a => a.A))
    .Concat(
        ctx.TableB.GroupBy(x => 1)
        .Select(g => g.Max(b => b.B))
    );
```

Also if You are not restricted with third party etensions usage: [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore), note that I'm one of the creators.

Then this query can be written in simple way

```cs
using var db = ctx.CreateLinqToDBConnection();

var result = db.Select(() => new 
    { 
        A = ctx.TableA.Max(a => a.A), 
        B = ctx.TableB.Max(b => b.B)    
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. Though it works, `UNION ALL` can only be used when the values are in the same type. And your extensions are very useful.