# Entity Framework multi select from multiple table with no relationship in one transaction

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to translate this SQL query.

`select (select sum(paid) from table_a) Paid, (select count(*) from table_b) ct`

And I'm hoping to do this with one transaction something like this.

```
await ctx.Select(u => new
{
   Paid = ctx.table_a.Sum(i => i.paid),
   Ct = ctx.table_b.Count(i => i.key)
}).ToArrayAsync();
```

But Entity Framework requires specifying an entity model to use Select().

The options I have considered are

1. Call it individually. -> This may be the fallback, but I'd like to use one transaction
2. Use ExecuteSqlRawAsync or ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync -> I'd like to avoid this

How can I use Select without specifying a model like ctx.Select();

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71294722/5045688